# 404 - File or directory not found redirect issue in wordpress when moving to new server

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Windows server for my WordPress blog and I am facing redirecting problem.

How to remove this error?

Comment: Login with wp-admin and then change and save permalink structure, then check will be working.

Comment: I've already tried this

Comment: You should provide more information about your problem to increase chances to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save you permalink from wp-admin.

[image]

Comment: @VikasJangra First take backup of you .htaccess file and then change your original permalink structure and then sav and then set same as old one. This is required because when you just same at that time noting change in .htaccess file but when you change your structure at that time its change and its working.